# @foreach php list object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

have now tried in 2 days to show the tables from the database (service_types)
With now luck, im new to laravel but i have manage to fix mulltiple problems, but this is giving me a headache.

in the index i have this code:

```
<h3 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">{{ trans('index.header_3') }}</h3>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="width: 100% !important">
            
@foreach($service_type as $index => $service)
<div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 00px; margin-right: 00px width: 30%">
@if($service->image) 
<img src="{{$service->image}}" style="height: 50px" >
@else
N/A
@endif<br>{{ $service->name }}
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
</div>
```

but nothing is shown.
Please help.

UPPDATE.
I create one ServiceTypeController.php and add it in the controller folder.

i add this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\ServiceType;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ServiceTypeController extends Controller {
public function index(){
$service_type = DB::select('select * from service_type');
return view('index',['service_type'=>$service_type]);
}
}
```

And in the web.php in routes:

```
Route::get('/','ServiceTypeController@index');
```

Still dont get any data on the page :(

Comment: Foreach'ın üstüne `@dd($service_type)` yazarak çıktıyı gönderebilir misiniz?

Comment: i get this ^ null please english

Comment: Actually, I copied the wrong part when copying from the translation, sorry for that. It looks like you have a problem with your controller. Send me the controller code.

Comment: I think that is the problem, i read now that i need to add in the controller, so i searching that now

Comment: If nothing is shown, your `$service_type` must be empty, right?  So what debugging have you done?  Have you tried to `dd($service_type);` in your controller to see what it looks like?  How is that value generated, have you tried debugging whatever query or code is setting that variable?  Are you sending the variable correctly to your view?  There is not enough info here for anyone to help.

Comment: you are trying to list the tables from a database? and what db engine are you using

Comment: i´m using .env to recive data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this when rotating the page in the Controller.

```
$service_type = "your db query";
return view('your-page', compact('service_type'));
```

You can also use commas to send more data to the view.

Example:

```
$service_type = "your db query";
$data1 = "aaa";
$data2 = "bbb";
return view('your-page', compact('service_type', 'data1', 'data2'));
```

Comment: I don´t know which controller, like i said i'm new to this.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/kaann.gunerr/ Send me anydesk info and i will help you.

Answer (score -1):

in PHP and many other languages, if array you are trying to loop over is empty, it will not do anything which might be what is happening in your code.

Try to debug your code by putting

```
{{ dd($service_type) }}
```

just before `@foreach` loop. Once php reaches `dd()` function, it will stop executing code and display content of that variable on screen.

Comment: this is not a helpful answer, you should put that as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

In your ServiceTypeController in the index function
do this:

```
public function index(){
$service_type = DB::table('service_type')->select('service_type.*')->get();
     return view('index')->with('service_type',$service_type);
}
```

Comment: this one doesent work. i dont see anything from db